# Vaadin notification in UI with Akka actor

Tags: java, akka, actor, vaadin7

I'm working on integrating an akka actors based backend within a vaadin application.
the problem i'm facing is i dare say simple (bear with me i'm a vaadin first timer :P).

**Project structure (simplified)**
2 modules front and backend.

- my backEnd has an actor system that manages all the backend actors.
  -> and a service class that has all relevant methods for necessary computations.
- my frontEnd contains a single UI with a bunch of views.
  -> and a second actor system that manages one UIActor (since backend actors can't access the UI)
  needless to say the back-end is part of the front-end's dependencies.

**The problem**
In one of my views i have a click event handler that sends a message through the UIActor to one of the backEnd actors which in turn answers back once computations are done.
this is the "onReceive" method in the UIActor

```
public void onReceive(Object message) throws Exception {

    if (message  == "test") {
        System.out.println("showing notification by "+currentUI);
        currentUI.testMethod();

    } else if (message instanceof MyUI) {
        System.out.println("this is the ui actor test request forwarded");
        currentUI = (MyUI) message;
        backEndAgent.tell("check",getSelf());
    } else {
        unhandled(message);
    }
}
```

the currentUI contains the return value of (MyUI) getCurrent(), sent as an message by the handler, in case you're wondering.

as for the testMethod it's pretty basic.

```
public void testMethod() {
        Notification.show("Success", Notification.Type.HUMANIZED_MESSAGE);
    }
```

unfortunately this call generates a null pointer in the Show method resulting from the Page.getCurrent() returning null.

So my question is why do i get a null pointer here?
also in my actor i send the currentUI reference as message because otherwise calling the getCurrent inside the UIActor returns null. any idea why?
**EDIT**
This is the new test method the page parameter is currentUI.getPage()

```
    public void testMethod(final Page page) {
            this.access(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    new Notification("Success",Notification.Type.HUMANIZED_MESSAGE).show(page);

                }
            });
        }
```

this solves the problem somehow but only shows the notification after i click the button a second time but not the first time.
This is driving me crazy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Notification.show()` uses `Page.getCurrent()` to fetch the current page. `Page.getCurrent()` is a `ThreadLocal` which is set during a traditional HTTP request-response cycle meaning that `Notification.show()` works (doesn't return `null`) during the HTTP request-response thread.

In you case `Notification.show()` is called outside the HTTP request-response thread and that's why it returns `null`. If I understand correctly from your code, `currentUI` is reference to your current UI and it's not `null`. In that case you could change your code from

```
public void testMethod() {
    Notification.show("Success", Notification.Type.HUMANIZED_MESSAGE);
}
```

to

```
public void testMethod() {
    new Notification("Success", Notification.Type.HUMANIZED_MESSAGE).show(getPage());
}
```

The modified version doesn't use `Page.getCurrent()` anymore but gets the current page from the `getPage()` method of your UI instance.

EDIT. Forgot to add important information related to actors / external threads accessing Vaadin code:

The actor calling the method to show a notification is an external thread from the Vaadin point of view. Vaadin assumes that access to Vaadin components and Vaadin related other objects is locked/syncronized properly. A proper locking/syncronization is in place when the traditional HTTP request-response thread is used but when an external thread (e.g. actor) is accessing those, the developer must ensure locking. One way to ensure locking is to use UI.access:

```
getUI().access(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // insert your code accessing Vaadin related objects here
    }
});
```

The reason why you see the notification after clicking a button is that browser doesn't know that there is something to show when an actor calls Notification.show. The request caused by a button click pulls changes from the server to the browser and then the notification is show. To see changes from actors / external threads without user interaction (e.g. a button click) the application must use polling or push. To enable polling, setPollInterval for your ui.

Comment: yep that's exactly it. but even this method doesn't work i tried it after posting this question. i edited my first post with the work around i am using.

Comment: Thanks i managed to make it work by enabling push from server side. Your answer pointed me to the right direction.